# Change QCalendarWidget grid visibility/thickness

Tags: qt, qwidget, qtableview, qtabwidget, qtstylesheets

I would like to make the `QCalendarWidget` grid visible. As far as I know the days part in a `QCalendarWidget` is implemented as a `QTableView` but I don't know how to modify the grid bar thickness of a `QTableView` either. I would like it to look something like this:

[image]

Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first lines of the [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcalendarwidget.html#details):

```
 QCalendarWidget *calendar;
 calendar->setGridVisible(true);
```

I'm so stupid....